# Failed to configure a DataSource: Intellij Error when connecting Database to Spring Application

Tags: java, mysql, spring, maven, intellij-idea

Please I really need help. I have looked at other questions posted similar and none of them have solved my problem. I am running a Spring application trying to connect to my local database and I keep getting the following error

> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not >specified and no embedded datasource could be >configured.
>
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
>
> Action:
>
> Consider the following:
>       If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
>       If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

This is my application.properties (yes it's in the resources folder):

```
>spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
>spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/CierraDB
>spring.datasource.username=
>spring.datasource.password=
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>read-db</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>mysql-jdbc-driver</name>
<description>example</description>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: You may also need to set the dialect: `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect` Still, the error complains about the driver.

Comment: When do you get this error? On running `mvn spring-boot:run` command?

Comment: @EugenCovaci I get the error trying to run the application in Intellij

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my application.properties was noticing an error with

> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

I just deleted `<scope>runtime</scope>` within my mysql dependency and it runs fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Do you specify the driver class and include the jar with the mysql driver class in your classpath?

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: Yes I just added this and tried to run this application and I'm still receiving the same error.

Comment: And your mysql drivers are in your classpath?

Comment: @Justin I'm new to Spring Boot, how do I confirm that's it has been added?